# Passar campo de tabela como parâmetro numa procedure

Tags: mysql, procedure, stored-procedures

Fiz essa procedure para trazer registros de uma tabela entre datas, mas preciso passar o campo data da tabela para o comando between funcionar, segue o código:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE pro_get_gastos(nome_tabela VARCHAR(20), data_ini DATETIME, data_fin DATETIME)
BEGIN
SET @tabela = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ',nome_tabela,' WHERE ', AQUI TERIA QUE PASSAR O CAMPO DATA, 'BETWEEN', data_ini, ' AND ', data_fin,'''')
PREPARE consulta_gastos FROM @tabela;
EXECUTE consulta_gastos;
END //
```

Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Precisa passar o campo DATA de qual Tabela ? Não entendi.

Comment: Todas as tabelas que utilizarei nessa procedure tem um campo data, o nome da tabela a ser consultada eu passei por parâmetro, porém, preciso do campo data dessas tabelas para utilizar no "where CAMPO_DATA between ..."

Answer (score 2):

Faz assim:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pro_get_gastos @nome_tabela sysname,
                                @data_mov    sysname,
                                @data_ini    datetime, 
                                @data_fim    datetime AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
    SELECT @sql = ' SELECT * ' +
              ' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@nome_tabela) +
              ' WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(@data_mov) + ' BETWEEN ' + 
              ' @data_ini AND @data_fim ' 

   EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@data_ini datetime, @data_fim datetime', @data_ini, @data_fim
END
```

Edit: No MySQL podes fazer assim:

```
delimiter // 
CREATE PROCEDURE pro_get_gastos (IN nome_tabela CHAR(20),
                                 IN data_mov    CHAR(20),
                                 IN data_ini    datetime, 
                                 IN data_fim    datetime)
BEGIN
    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', nome_tabela, ' WHERE ', data_mov, ' BETWEEN ', data_ini, ' AND ', data_fim);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Ele dá o seguinte erro na declaração de @nome_tabela:
Syntax error: '@nome_tabela' (at text suffix) is not valid input on this position

Comment: Podes verificar desta forma?

Comment: É que você fez utilizando a sintaxe de SQL Server, certo? Uso o mysql

Comment: Momento de burrice da minha parte. Eu vou actualizar a resposta para a syntax do MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Cria um parâmetro a mais além do `nome_tabela`, ficando:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pro_get_gastos(
    nome_tabela VARCHAR(20), 
    nome_data VARCHAR(20), 
    data_ini DATETIME, 
    data_fin DATETIME)
```

E na concatenação você passa igual passou a tabela

```
CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ',nome_tabela,' WHERE ', nome_data, ...
```

Comment: Porém eu não queria passar uma data, apenas pegar o campo data da tabela que passei como parâmetro, para poder utilizar no "where CAMPO_DATA between ..."

Comment: @Mamedio Por isso mesmo um novo parâmetro, meu `nome_data` é igual seu `campo_data`

Comment: nesse 2º parâmetro não é o valor da data e sim o nome da coluna

Comment: Certo, mas apenas declarando esse novo parâmetro, não resolve, pois preciso que esse novo parâmetro seja o campo data da tabela escolhida...

Comment: Como você está chamando a procedure?

Comment: Seria assim: CALL pro_get_gastos ('nomeDaTabela', '2015-01-01', '2015-06-06');

Comment: E qual a dificuldade de chamar `CALL pro_get_gastos ('nomeDaTabela', 'nomeDaColunaData', '2015-01-01', '2015-06-06');`

Comment: Não está rodando...

Comment: Qual o erro que aparece?

Comment: Erro de sintaxe...Pensei em fazer assim: 
SET @data_mov = CONCAT(SELECT * FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = orcpessoal AND TABLE_NAME = nome_tabela AND COLUMN_NAME  = data_mov);
Porém não estou conseguindo concatenar de forma correta...

Comment: Sempre vai ser `data_mov`?

Comment: Erro de sintaxe pode ser pq você não criou a procedure corretamente com a minha alteração

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24962/discussion-between-mamedio-and-maicon-carraro).

Answer (score 0):

---

-- TROCA DE DELIMITADOR:

---

DELIMITER $$

USE `AUDITOR`$$

CREATE DEFINER=CURRENT_USER PROCEDURE `AUDITOR`.`SP_INTERVALO_DATA`(DT_INI DATE, DT_FIM DATE)
BEGIN

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE @TBDATA(`DATA` DATE);

WHILE(DATE(DT_INI) <= DATE(DT_FIM)) DO

    INSERT INTO @TBDATA(`DATA`) VALUES(DT_INI);
    
    SET DT_INI = DATE_ADD(DT_INI, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
    
END WHILE;
```

END$$

---

-- TROCA DE DELIMITADOR (PADRÃO)

---

DELIMITER ;

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).